# dplyr mutating multiple columns by prefix and suffix

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a problem that I can replicate using the iris dataset, where many groups (same prefix in name) of variables with two different suffixes. I want to be take a ratio for all these groups but can't find a tidyverse solution.. I would have through `mutate_at()` might have been able to help.

In the iris dataset you could consider for Petal columns I want to generate a Petal proportion of Length / Width. Similarly I want to do this for Sepal. I don't want to manually do this in a `mutate()` because I have lots of variable groups, and this could change over time.

I do have a solution that works using base R (in the code below) but I wanted to know if there was a tidyverse solution that achieved the same.

```
# libs ----
library(tidyverse)

# data ----
df <- iris
glimpse(df)

# set up column vectors ----
length_cols <- names(df) %>% str_subset("Length") %>% sort()
width_cols <- names(df) %>% str_subset("Width") %>% sort()
new_col_names <- names(df) %>% str_subset("Length") %>% str_replace(".Length", ".Ratio") %>% sort()

length_cols
width_cols
new_col_names

# make new cols ----
df[, new_col_names] <- df[, length_cols] / df[, width_cols]
df %>% head()
```

Thanks,
Gareth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility using `purrr::map`:

```
library(tidyverse);
df <- map(c("Petal", "Sepal"), ~ iris %>%
    mutate(
        !!paste0(.x, ".Ratio") := !!as.name(paste0(.x, ".Length")) / !!as.name(paste0(.x, ".Width")) )) %>%
    reduce(left_join);
head(df);
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Petal.Ratio
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa        7.00
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa        7.00
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa        6.50
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa        7.50
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa        7.00
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa        4.25
#  Sepal.Ratio
#1    1.457143
#2    1.633333
#3    1.468750
#4    1.483871
#5    1.388889
#6    1.384615
```

Explanation: We `map` the prefixes `"Petal"` and `"Sepal"` to `iris` by extracting for each prefix the columns with suffixes `"Length"` and `"Width"`, and calculate a new corresponding prefix + `".Ratio"` column; `reduce` merges both `data.frame`s.